# Upsert-update the row if specific field is not same

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo db. I have a specific problem where I have to update the row only if the field in that document is not same. Here is the below example

Lets consider the below data with seller & ASIN as unique fields.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572dc897bde92c7907ffaf71"), "seller" : "amazon", "ASIN" : "XYZ", "price" : 46, "lastUpdatedate" : ISODate("2016-05-07T10:59:11.165Z") }
```

Now I have one of 2 tasks.

1. Insert the new row only if seller & ASIN are unique
2. Update the above id only if Price is not same. Example If I upsert the same seller & ASIN with Price: 47 then it should upsert the above row and if the price is 46 then it should not do any changes. 
   Ideally the field lastUpdatedate should remain same if price remains unchanged.

After this I will query only the rows with lastupdatedate changed < yesterday and upload the data to other module. This will greatly reduce the data to upload to other module.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Aggregation Pipeline Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

Answer (score 0):

## First issue

MongoDB's [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command has an optional `upsert` parameter which...

> ...if set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

You can use it this way:

`db.yourCollection.update({ seller: 'amazon', ASIN: 'XYZ'}, { ...your new document... }, { upsert: true })`

This will tell MongoDB to insert a new document **only** if it does not find an existing document where seller is 'amazon' and ASIN is 'XYZ'. If it **does** find an exisiting document, it will replace it with the new document, but as far as I understand your situation, this is not relevant.

## Second issue

In order to update the price field only if the new one is higher than the existing one, you can use the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) operator which...

> ...updates the value of the field to a specified value if the specified value is greater than the current value of the field.

You can use it this way:
`db.yourCollection.update({ seller: 'amazon', ASIN: 'XYZ'}, { $max: {price: newPrice} }, { upsert: true })`

Regarding the lastUpdatedate field - I cannot think of a way to conditionally update it within the same update operation. I think you need to get the result of the update operation to determine if price has been updated, and if so - update the lastUpdatedate.

Answer (score 0):

1. If seller and ASIN combination is unique. You should create unique index on them.Then it will never insert(upsert) new document with similar seller and ASIN combination. Ref. [Compound-unique-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index)
2. Then in your query document of update add one more condition `$ne: {"price":new_price}`

So it will never upsert(insert) new document and also won't update your existing document if price is same.